PoE power extractions using RT9400
I want to get power using RT9400. The thing is I have schematics for RT9400 connections diagram in which they used magnetic transformer.
My question is can I directly  use RT9400 with PoE connector to extract power without using magnetic transformer?
Please see attached pic below and let me know.



can I directly use RT9400 with PoE connector to extract power without using magnetic transformer?

Short answer: Yes, as long as the PSE (power sourcing equipment) decides operation mode is Mode B or it's a Mode-B injector.
A note here: On this page it's stated that a A 24V PD (powered device i.e. the "load" of the PSE) is generally mode B, but a 48V or 56V PD can be either but the default mode is A.

There are two modes of PoE:

Mode A: Power is delivered over the RX/TX pairs. VA1 and VA2 pins accept power input through the centre taps of the network magnetics. Hence the name VA which indicates Mode A.
Mode B: Power is delivered over the spare pins (pins 4-5 and 7-8 of the RJ45). VB1 and VB2 pins accept power input through these pins. Hence the name VB which indicates Mode B.

The VA and VB pins of your module have bridge rectifiers which have their outputs in parallel to form a Power-OR:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
In order for the DC voltage to be available on the RJ45 connector, the PSE (power sourcing equipment) needs to detect the presence of a PoE-compliant device (PD: Powered device). Your RT9400 module is able to respond to that detection phase as a Class-0 device. So, as long as the PSE works on Mode B only or somehow selects Mode B you don't need the ethernet magnetics.

There's an issue if you care about standards compliance and interoperability: Power on A or B is up to the PSE, 802.3 2012 says : "A PSE shall implement Alternative A, Alternative B, or both" (33.2.3) and "PDs that implement only Mode A or Mode B are specifically not allowed by this standard." (33.3.1)

@jonathanjo oh, that's a detail I missed. Thanks for pointing out. Updating my answer accordingly.

It's a detail I learned very expensively.  But given the number of "passive POE" (just PO-cat5, really) devices on the market, there are many people who find the standard irrelevant in their circumstances.

"24V POE" .. my understanding is that this is always "passive POE", ie "just use the wires".  I think the OP is asking about negotiated "real" POE, or they wouldn't be using a POE module.
